# Error when trying to read AWS SNS message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-rekognition

I need to return the message sent by Rekognition to SNS but I get this error in  CloudWatch:

> 'Records': KeyError Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/var/task/AnalyzeVideo/lambda_function.py", line 34, in
>   lambda_handler message = event["Records"][0]["Sns"]["Message"]
>   KeyError: 'Records'

Code:

```
def detect_labels(bucket, key):
    response = rekognition.start_label_detection(
        Video = {
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": BUCKET,
                "Name": KEY
            }
        },
        NotificationChannel = {
            "SNSTopicArn": TOPIC_ARN,
            "RoleArn": ROLE_ARN
        }
    )

    return response

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reko_response = detect_labels(BUCKET, KEY)
    message = event["Records"][0]["Sns"]["Message"]
    return message
```

And is this the correct way of implementing Rekognition stored video in AWS Lambda with python I didn't find any examples on it.

Update:

The steps my app needs to take are:

1. In the frontend, the user triggers a lambda function with API gateway which 
   sends a file to s3
2. When the file arrives trigger the same lambda function to apply video 
   recognition and send jobId to SNS
3. when SNS receives a message trigger the same lambda function to get the 
   label data and return the data back to the user with API gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is calling `rekognition.start_label_detection()` (and presumably you have created the `rekognition` client in code not shown).

This API call starts label detection on a video. When it is finished, it will publish a message to the given SNS topic. You can connect a Lambda function to SNS to retrieve the details of the label detection when it is finished.

However, your code is getting the order of operations mixed up. Instead, you should be doing the following:

- Something (probably not a Lambda function) should call `start_label_detection()` to begin the process of scanning the video. This can take several minutes.
- A Lambda function should be configured to trigger when the SNS topic receives a message.
- The Lambda function is then passed a copy of the message, which can be used to call `get_label_detection()` to retrieve the details of the scan.

So, your first step is to separate the initial `start_label_detection()` request from the code that retrieves the results. Then, modify the Lambda function to retrieve the results via `get_label_detection()` and process the results.

Comment: So I should create another lambda function to call 'start_label_detection' , then have another lambda function get triggered when it receives the SNS message with 'event["Records"][0]["Sns"]["Message"]' and then call 'get_label_detection' ? And when you say something not a lambda function should call 'start_label_detection' what does that mean?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do. **Question 1:** What will be triggering this whole process? (I don't mean a Lambda, I mean what happens in the outside world to start this whole process?) **Question 2:** What do you want to do what once the video has been processed? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Thank you for the update. You will want three Lambda functions: One to respond to the original API request, one to respond to the S3 event that signals that a new object has been created, and one to respond to SNS when it says that the video has been processed. They should be separate Lambda functions because each one is doing something different.

Comment: Ok, so how can I return the label data back to the original API request

Comment: You don't. The first request starts the label detection. When the label detection is finished, it will trigger a different Lambda function to do whatever it is you want to do with it. Lambda functions are best when they do one small thing. They aren't like normal programs that hang around forever.