# can one aws lambda function handle multiple triggers at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I have an aws lambda function. When it receives only one trigger, it always succeds. But when it receives more than one trigger, it sometimes throws error. The first trigger always succeds.

Can I configure one aws lambda function receives only one trigger?

Comment: see these answers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130628/how-to-trigger-the-same-lambda-function-with-multiple-triggers

Answer (score 0):

> can one aws lambda function handle multiple triggers at once?

Yes, Lambda functions can handle multiple triggers at once.

> when it receives more than one trigger, it sometimes throws error

This is most probably related to your implementation. Are you doing something different based on the inputs? Is the code behaving differently based on time?

> Can I configure one aws lambda function receives only one trigger?

You can limit the concurrency of the Lambda function. If you set it to 1, you can only have one Lambda function running at any given time.

See: [Set Concurrency Limits on Individual AWS Lambda Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/set-concurrency-limits-on-individual-aws-lambda-functions/)